# Synology Cloud Station selective folder synchronization

Tags: cloud, synology

I'm in a lab and we share a Synology RS411 with the package 'Cloud Station' installed. We have a folder called 'LabUsers' and several subfolders under it for user-a, user-b, till user-z. Everyone has read+write permission for her/his own subfolder and has read access to others' subfolder. I'm user-c.

I installed the Win client on my PC and all I can select is whether to sync user-z's folder. I have no idea how this happened. Please help, thanks.

Here's a screenshot link:

[image]